# Is it possible to created different nsg with single template for 2 different Azure VM using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, network-security-groups

I want to create the 2 Azure VMs using the single template json file with different NSGs.

vm-template.json

```
  "resources": [
    {
        "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "apiVersion": "[variables('computeApiVersion')]",
        "location": "[variables('location')]",
        "tags": {
            "Created By": "PAMC"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "osProfile": {
                "computerName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
                "adminUsername": "[parameters('vmUsername')]",
                "adminPassword": "[parameters('vmPassword')]"
            },
            "hardwareProfile": {
                "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
            },
            "storageProfile": {
                "imageReference": {
                    "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
                    "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
                    "sku": "[variables('imageSku')]",
                    "version": "latest"
                }
            },
            "networkProfile": {
                "networkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "apiVersion": "[variables('networkApiVersion')]",
        "location": "[variables('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/', parameters('publicIPAddressName'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "ipConfigurations": [
                {
                    "name": "ipconfig1",
                    "properties": {
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                        },
                        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                        "publicIpAddress": {
                            "id": "[resourceId(variables('resourceGroupName'),'Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', parameters('publicIPAddressName'))]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                "id": "[resourceId(variables('resourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "[parameters('publicIPAddressName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses",
        "apiVersion": "[variables('networkApiVersion')]",
        "location": "[variables('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "publicIpAllocationMethod": "[variables('publicIPAddressType')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "nsg1",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
        "apiVersion": "[variables('networkApiVersion')]",
        "location": "[variables('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "securityRules": [
                {
                    "name": "default-allow-ssh",
                    "properties": {
                        "priority": 1000,
                        "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "destinationPortRange": "22",
                        "access": "Allow",
                        "direction": "Inbound",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*",
                        "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "port1",
                    "properties": {
                        "priority": 1010,
                        "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "destinationPortRange": "[parameters('port1')]",
                        "access": "Allow",
                        "direction": "Inbound",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*",
                        "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": 'nsg2')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
        "apiVersion": "[variables('networkApiVersion')]",
        "location": "[variables('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "securityRules": [
                {
                    "name": "default-allow-ssh",
                    "properties": {
                        "priority": 1000,
                        "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "destinationPortRange": "22",
                        "access": "Allow",
                        "direction": "Inbound",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*",
                        "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "port2",
                    "properties": {
                        "priority": 1010,
                        "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "destinationPortRange": "[parameters('port2')]",
                        "access": "Allow",
                        "direction": "Inbound",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*",
                        "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "port3",
                    "properties": {
                        "priority": 1020,
                        "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "destinationPortRange": "[parameters('port3')]",
                        "access": "Allow",
                        "direction": "Inbound",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*",
                        "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  ]
```

I will call above vm-template.json from another template 2 times with different parameters.

```
 {
        "apiVersion": "[variables('resourceDeploymentApiVersion')]",
        "name": "template1",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "[variables('vmTemplateURL')]"
            },
            "parameters": {
                ....
            }
        }             
    },
 {
        "apiVersion": "[variables('resourceDeploymentApiVersion')]",
        "name": "template2",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "[variables('vmTemplateURL')]"
            },
            "parameters": {
                ....
            }
        }             
    },
```

How do I use the nsg1 for template1 and nsg2 for template2 with in vm-template.json?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a problem there, just create a new parameter for nsg name and use it to create NSG and link it to the vm. Also, it appears you should be using copies for this, it makes more sense (at least to me).

in case they have different rules, you can use variables to create proper rules:

```
"baseRule":     [
    {
        "name": "default-allow-ssh",
        "properties": {
            "priority": 1000,
            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "destinationPortRange": "22",
            "access": "Allow",
            "direction": "Inbound",
            "sourcePortRange": "*",
            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "port2",
        "properties": {
            "priority": 1010,
            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "destinationPortRange": "[parameters('port2')]",
            "access": "Allow",
            "direction": "Inbound",
            "sourcePortRange": "*",
            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
        }
    }
],
"extendedRule": [
    {
        "name": "port3",
        "properties": {
            "priority": 1020,
            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "destinationPortRange": "[parameters('port3')]",
            "access": "Allow",
            "direction": "Inbound",
            "sourcePortRange": "*",
            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
        }
    }
]
```

and use this to constuct proper rule:

```
"securityRules": "[if(equals(nsgname, firstnsg), variables('baseRule'), concat(variables('baseRule'), variables('extendedRule'))]"
```

Comment: It will create 2 NSGs for 1st and 2nd vms. How to specific nsg link it to the specifi VM?

Comment: just like you normally would run same template two times with different input to get 2 vms, just do the same here, just with nested deployment in your case. just like in this template: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/ae137b08f229f2cbc29bef0fc0e397993f81293d/101-VM-Virus-Attack-Prevention/azuredeploy.json

Comment: Each NSG have different security rules, So I don't know how to link it for each VMs. I can pass the different NSG name for 2 vms if it has same security rules and make it work.